# AVL tree insert case need a clarify

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I read several online document about implementing AVL tree using balance factor(**Not using a height data field in Node structure**), when insert into the tree, there is one case I could not figure out.

The document is [from here](http://kabulcs.weebly.com/uploads/5/0/3/5/5035021/chapter_8_-_avl_trees.pdf)(also [from here](https://cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs310/slides/avl.pdf) has similar function) , the balance factor is defined as height(right-subtree) - height(left-subtree), value in [-1,0,1].

Insert method is implemented as :

```
public avlitem insertAVL(avlitem root, avlitem newstudent) 
{
    if(root == null) {
        root = newstudent;
        unbalance = true;
    }
    else if(root.idno == newstudent.idno)
        System.err.println("No duplicates are allowed");
    else if (root.idno > newstudent.idno)
    {
        root.leftchild=insertAVL(root.leftchild, newstudent);
        if (unbalance )     
        {
            switch(root.bfactor)
            {   case -1:
                    root = balancefromleft(root);
                    unbalance=false;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    root.bfactor = -1;
                    unbalance = true;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    root.bfactor = 0;
                    unbalance = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        root.rightchild=insertAVL(root.rightchild, newstudent);
        if (unbalance )
        {
            switch(root.bfactor)
            {
                case -1 : 
                    root.bfactor = 0;
                    unbalance = false;
                    break;
                case 0: 
                    root.bfactor=1;
                    unbalance = true;
                    break;
                case 1 : 
                    root = balancefromright(root);
                    unbalance = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

And insert into the left child ,we use **balancefromleft** to reblance the tree:

```
public avlitem balancefromleft(avlitem root) 
{
    avlitem p;
    avlitem w;
    p = root.leftchild;
    switch(p.bfactor)
    {
        case -1:
            root.bfactor=0;
            p.bfactor = 0;
            root = rotatetoright(root);
            break;
        case 0 : System.err.println("can't balance from the left");break;
        case 1 : w = p.rightchild;
        {
            switch (w.bfactor)
            {
                case -1:root.bfactor = 1;p.bfactor = 0;break;
                case 0: root.bfactor = 0; p.bfactor = 0;break; // what is this case ?
                case 1: root.bfactor = 0;p.bfactor = -1;
            }
            w.bfactor = 0;
            p = rotatetoleft(p);
            root.leftchild = p;
            root = rotatetoright(root);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

In the above balancefromleft function, we have a right rotate and double rotate case.

**1)The right rotate case is** : insert into left child of node y.

`T1, T2, T3 and T4 are subtrees.
         z                                      y 
        / \                                   /   \
       y   T4      Right Rotate (z)          x      z
      / \          - - - - - - - - ->      /  \    /  \ 
     x   T3                               T1  T2  T3  T4
    / \
  T1   T2`

**2) The left then right rotate case:** insert into right child of y.

     `z                               z                           w
    / \                            /   \                        /  \ 
   y   T4  Left Rotate (y)        w    T4  Right Rotate(z)    y      z
  / \      - - - - - - - - ->    /  \      - - - - - - - ->  / \    / \
T1   w                          y    T3                    T1  T2 T3  T4
    / \                        / \
  T2   T3                    T1   T2`

**My question:**
In the left-then-right rotate case, what case can cause the w.bfactor = 0 ?
In my mind, this could only be possible when remove node of T4 and T4 become shorter than before.How could it be possible when insert node ?

```
switch (w.bfactor)
{
  case -1:root.bfactor = 1;p.bfactor = 0;break;
  case 0: root.bfactor = 0; p.bfactor = 0;break; // what is this case ?
  case 1: root.bfactor = 0;p.bfactor = -1;
}
```